# Contribute function of crowdsale is not working

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, contract-development

I am having a crowdsale contract. I am trying to run `contribute` function using command: `contractInstance.contribute.sendTransaction(101,{from:eth.accounts[0],value:200, gas:4000000})`. It is creating a transaction hash. After mining I can see the `value = 200` and `to: contractAddress`. But it doesn't increase the contract balance. I am getting no error. My contribute function is as:

```
function contribute(uint _campaignID){       
    Campaign c = campaigns[_campaignID];      
    uint256 amount = msg.value; 
    c.balanceOf[msg.sender] = amount;    
    c.amountRaised += amount;
    check = 'check4';
    token.transfer(msg.sender,amount/c.tokenValue); 
    check = 'check5';
    FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, true);      //event     
}
```

Variable `check` is used for testing purpose. Even `check` variable is not updated. It is working fine in solidity browser. I am using geth client. Please tell me where i am wrong?

Comment: Quick note, you should make it `c.balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount;` to allow for more than 1 contribution per sender.

Comment: When coming in the function, you should make sure the campaign exists. Perhaps check that `c.tokenValue > 0`.

Comment: Remove the `token.transfer` line, perhaps it is the one `throw`ing.

Comment: Yeah, one check was throwing error in transfer function, now it is resolved, Thanks!!